# How to create a custom color bar - Matplotlib / Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, opacity, colorbar

I'm merging to data in the same plot using **Matplotlib**.

With the colors, I represent the data *a*, and with opacity, the data *b*.
So, at the end, I have something like:

[image]

As can be seen, so far my color bar just represent the data from *a*. Currently, my background is grey, but I'll change that.

I would like to combine it with some opacity to show the **b** property too.

Something like these two images below.

Not exactly that (with this labels and so on), but using the same idea: the "first" bar representing the *a* property (with the properly labels), with no opacity, and, for the "next" bars, these color with the opacity value ranging from 0 to 1.

[image]

Another possibility, but I think is less "readable", would be something like this:

[image]

Is that possible to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Suggest you use imshow on new array you create where the value varies in one direction and opacity in the other (and don't use colorbar).

Comment: This is not something mpl currently does.  When you get this working please contribute it back up stream.